# Can someone please fix this loop? It has errors in iterating next value and saving array data

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, loops, for-loop

Here is the loop.

```
 for(let k = 0; k <2; k++) {

        await dmb.page.waitForSelector('a > div > div.Igw0E.rBNOH.YBx95.ybXk5._4EzTm.soMvl > div[class]');

        await dmb.page.click('a > div > div.Igw0E.rBNOH.YBx95.ybXk5._4EzTm.soMvl > div[class]');

        await dmb.page.waitFor(2000);

            for(let i  = 0; i < textbycomma.length; i++){

                let type = textbycomma[i];

                await dmb.page.waitForSelector('textarea[placeholder="Message..."]');

                await dmb.page.type('textarea[placeholder="Message..."]', type , {delay: 100});

                let toClick = await dmb.page.$x('//button[contains(text(), "Send")]');

                await toClick[0].click();

                await dmb.page.waitFor(2000);
                
                let readurls = []

                readurls[k] = dmb.page.url();

                var hrefs = {

                    href : readurls

                }
            
                fs.writeFileSync('./savedlinks.json', JSON.stringify(hrefs));

                if(i = textbycomma.length){

                    break;
 
                }

            }

            await dmb.page.goto('https://www.example.com');

        }
```

Please see here for references:

```
script: async(text = []) => {

        var textbycomma = [] = text.toString().split(',');
```

This is my example data:

```
Console:

text : Hello, Nice

textbycomma : ['Hello','Nice']

Loop variable *i* value remains 0 as many times as the loop runs. This only sends the 1st message (Hello) to the users.

In my savedlinks.json, the value saved is:

{"href":[null,"https://www.example.com/"]}
```

What I want to do with this loop is to send the first message `Hello` save the sent message urls to my `savedlinks.json`.

In a `cronjob` of 1 hour delay, this scripts runs again and checks if the urls match the new users urls, if not it sends the first message and if yes, it send the send message `Nice`.

Comment: Unrelated, but why to you turn the array into a string and then split it apart into an array again? Noting that this could lead to bugs if the strings contain commas.

Comment: I am a novice at development, so this seemed the easiest.

Comment: Easiest way to what? It's already an array; you're converting it into a string and back *in* to an array, with the possibility of introducing a bug.

Comment: Don't mind that, can you help me with the loop please?